# TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable when using pandas' date_range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm using pandas' `date_range` to generate datetime arrays:

`time_array = pd.date_range(start='2020-6-1 00:00:00', end='2021-10-31 00:00:00', freq='H')`

And when I start to debug my code, my IDE tells me this error:

```
past_predict_single.py::test_gen_line_model FAILED                       
past_predict_single.py:83 (test_gen_line_model)
def test_gen_line_model():
        back_hours = 72  
>       time_array = pd.date_range(start='2020-6-1 00:00:00', end='2021-10-31 00:00:00', freq='H')
E       TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

But when I run my code, this error diappears.

And another interesting thing: after the error appeared on the 1st computer, I chose the 2nd computer to debug my code, but after running my code for several times, the 2nd computer also appeared this problem.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cut my code to another python file and the problem disappeared.